# Fetch more than one google calendar using javascript node-fetch

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, google-calendar-api

I'm trying to build a site that shows the events of multiple calendars, using the google calendar API. I followed a youtube tutorial of [@CodinginPublic](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLoqZcxvpWzzeuzWsIpH-N1b3vnRVbrdm3) .
He does the event page with a serverless function (i'm not sure if it's relevant), and uses only one calendar.

I tried to loop on all the calendars_id i have and put the data collected in an array, but on my main file the array shows as empty.
I don't really know what to do.
i hope you'll help me.

This is the code from the serverless function in the file 'calFetch.mjs'

```
exports.handler = async function (event, context){
    
    const datas = [];

    try{
        if(event.httpMethod === "GET" ){
            for(i=0; i<urls.length; i++){
                fetch(urls[i])
                .then((response) => response.json())
                .then((data) => {
                    datas.push(data.items);
                })
            }
            return  {
                statusCode: 200,
                body: JSON.stringify(datas),
                HEADERS,
            }   
        }
        return {
            statusCode: 401
        }
    } catch(e){
        console.error(e)
        return {
            statusCode: 500,
            body: e.toString()
        }
    }
}
```

This is what's in my 'main.js' file

```
async function loadEvents(){
  try{
    const endpoint = await fetch(`./.netlify/functions/calFetch`);
    const data= await endpoint.json();
    console.log(data)
    const processedEvents = data.map(e => mapEventObject(e));
    eventContainer.innerHTML = processedEvents.map((event, i) => createEvent(event, i)).join('')
    // createTitle(data[0]);
  }catch(e){
    eventContainer.innerHTML = `<p class="text-center text-3xl">Erroreeeee</p>`;
    console.log(e);
  }
}
loadEvents();;
```

I hope it's understandable